# Angular ng-model-options for a Select List within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am struggling to get my head around this.

In my JSON I have:

```
"TargetMeasures": 
[{
    "Name": "Electricity",
    "AnnualTarget_MeasureId": 1,
    "SelectList": [
            {
              "Text": "kWh",
              "Value": "1",
              "Selected": false
            },
            {
              "Text": "mmBTU",
              "Value": "2",
              "Selected": false
            }
          ],
}]
```

I have a repeater where I want a select list to appear:

```
<div ng-repeat="measure in TargetMeasures">
  <select name="{{ measure.Name }}_MeasureId"
    data-ng-model="measure.AnnualTarget_MeasureId"
    data-ng-model-options="XXX"></select>
</div>
```

I can't get my head around what I would need to put in XXX to ensure I get the right  tags in my output.

I have tried reading the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) and some other questions on here, and so far the best I could come up with is "Text for Value in measure.SelectList".

This gives me: *"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'for' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression"*

Comment: it is ng-options not ng-model-options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive name is wrong, it should be `ng-options="Text for Value in measures.SelectList"`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll read the documentation more carefully next time. I was also getting [Object Object] as the output for my Select Lists, but fixed that with `ng-options="obj.Text for obj in measure.AnnualTarget_Measure_SelectList"`